# C++: overloading "pointer to object" * operator

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I was some misunderstanding about default operator definition(by compiler).

I have small class:

```
class Q
{
public:
    Q() {};
    Q(int i) { x = i; };
    ~Q() {};
    void print() { cout << x << endl; };
    Q& operator * ()
    {
        cout << "operator *\n";
        return *this;
    };
    const Q& operator * () const
    {
        cout << "operator *\n";
        return *this;
    };
private:
    int x;
};
```

And i'm doing this whit it:

```
int main()
{
    Q* obj_p = new Q(1);
    Q obj = *obj_p;
    obj.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to see `operator *`, before `1`. But I saw only `print()` method result.

What does it mean? That I don't need to overload `operator *` - it's compiler work or that I do overloading somehow wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj_p` is a pointer. You have not overloaded (and cannot do it anyway) the de-reference operator for a pointer. To invoke your overload, you need to act on an instance:

```
Q obj;
*obj;
```

Comment: And can you tell me, please: what about 'new' operator.<br> Should I overload it(in simple cases, not so simple like that, but still)? Or compiler will allocate exactly as much memory for my class as I need?

Comment: @KirillTimofeev You need to overload the `operator new` function if, and only if, your class needs some special allocation (typically, a pool allocator, or some such).  Such cases are rare.

Answer (score 1):

There's no user-defined operator called - `obj_p` is a pointer, not an object, so the built-in dereference operator is called.

To complete juanchopanza's answer, you can call your operator on a pointer like so:

```
Q* obj_p = new Q(1);
Q obj = obj_p->operator*();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use your '*' operator on Q pointer but you should use on Q objects. if you try *(*obj_p) you will see.